# OpenSocial API stopped working in Google Calendar Gadget

Tags: google-calendar-api, opensocial, google-gadget, google-oauth

I found out that opensocial API we were using in Calendar Sidebar Gadget stopped working. It was still working correctly on Friday. We were using opensocial to store and get some key-value data, and today we are getting error code: badRequest (with no error message) everytime we are trying to read anything.

This an example of the code we are using:

```
var idspec = opensocial.newIdSpec({ "userId" : "VIEWER", "groupId" : "SELF" });
var req = opensocial.newDataRequest();
req.add(req.newFetchPersonAppDataRequest(idspec, "mydata"), "get_data");
req.send(function(data){console.log(data)});
```

And this is the response we are getting from google:

```
errorMessage_: undefined
  globalError_: true
  responseItems_: Object
  get_data: opensocial.ResponseItem
    data_: null
    errorCode_: "badRequest"
    errorMessage_: undefined
```

The code is quite simillar to what is described here: http://docs.opensocial.org/display/OSREF/App+Data

Does anyone have some similar problem, or know how to fix it? We are using it on our production system which is down since morning. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i am too facing this problem while importing google email contacts. THe api's seems to be not working anymore ? Did anyone found out the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The API has been deprecated. For solving this i changed the implementation for importing Google Contacts with Google oAuth 2.0 and its working fine with it.

https://developers.google.com/igoogle/docs/opensocial_rest_rpc ( deprecated one ).

For using Google oAuth 2.0 visit below link :-

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login